# Are there any official statistics on average rejected/missing/lost ballots by mail?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, vote-by-mail

Some time ago, Washington Post presented an [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2020/05/21/heres-problem-with-mail-in-ballots-they-might-not-be-counted/) about flaws of mail voting. Another [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/tens-of-thousands-of-mail-ballots-have-been-tossed-out-in-this-years-primaries-what-will-happen-in-november/2020/07/16/fa5d7e96-c527-11ea-b037-f9711f89ee46_story.html) tells about "tens of thousands" such ballots.

And that caused me to ask this question:

**Is there any known average amount of missing/rejected/not counted mail ballots?**

For example, in 2016 elections?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the Election Administration and Voting Survey - conducted biennially since 2004 by the Election Assistance Commission - collects this data.

The 2016 report can be found [here](https://www.eac.gov/sites/default/files/eac_assets/1/6/2016_EAVS_Comprehensive_Report.pdf). In particular:

> Approximately 80.1 percent of absentee ballots that were transmitted
> to voters were returned and processed, with 1.4 percent of transmitted
> ballots returned as undeliverable and 2 percent reported as spoiled
> (e.g., the voter returned the ballot and asked for a replacement).
>
> Ninety-nine percent of absentee ballots categorized as “returned and submitted for counting”
> were ultimately counted in the 2016 election.

[image]

To put a raw figure on the number of ballots rejected, the report also states that "Nationally, by-mail voting constituted 23.7 percent of all votes cast in the 2016 election".

The [FEC](https://www.fec.gov/resources/cms-content/documents/federalelections2016.pdf) gives the total number of votes cast in 2016 as 136,669,276, so, according to the EAVS, there were approximately 32,390,000 by-mail ballots cast. As these, presumably, are the 99% which were counted, this means that approximately 327,000 by-mail ballots returned were rejected. As 19.9% of ballots sent to voters were not returned, we can calculate this figure as around 8,128,000, of which around 572,000 were returned as undeliverable, and 816,000 reported as spoiled.

Comment: This is an excellent answer; while the question doesn't ask for it, the only thing I might hope for would be a comparison to the percentages of in-person votes that are rejected and reasons therefor.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm interpreting that table right, the rows below "rejected (total)" are a subset of "rejected (total)," so late ballots made up 23.1% of that 1% of ballots that were rejected. Is that the right way to read that?

Comment: @DavyM Exactly - it's a pretty weird way to lay it out, but that's how I think it's meant to be interpreted.

Comment: So would that mean of all of the ballots 0.275% (1.0% x 27.5%) had a mis-matched signature? Which lets say 50% of those were because the signature changed (say changed name and signature after getting married) So it is possible that 0.1375% (0.275% x 50%) were fraudulent. Is my understanding of those numbers correct (Assuming my 50% of mis-matched have legitimate signature change assumption is correct)?

Comment: @darcy I mean, 50% is totally made up, so I would hesitate to say you're correct. Furthermore, check out NYT's article on signature matching. I think guessing at how many signatures are fraudulent is pointless. There's no evidence tens of thousands of ballots were forged that way in 2016